# How to find peak in time-series

Tags: matlab, graph, time-series

I have some data in Matlab, seen plotted below.
At the start and end of the graph is noise, I want to find the location of the peaks, but don't know how.

I found the problem that data before 80 and after 180 on x-axis will be detect like a peaks to. how to solve it?

For example, in this plot I want to identify the 5 peaks shown.

[image: graph example]

Comment: You need to show what code you've *tried* see [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See [`findpeaks`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html). But what is the criterion to relect the small peak close to abscissa 135 for example? Currently your problem is not well defined

Comment: Yes, my problem is when I use findpeaks small will be detect too but i want to ignore it. and i want to detect and delete some noise before 80 and after 180 too.